# Generate PDF with wkhtmltopdf on symfony2

Tags: php, linux, symfony, pdf, centos

I generate a PDF from symfony2 with the library wkhtmltopdf. The html is a twig layout with some variables to display. The generation works but stranges symbols replace latin caracters. If I copy-paste symbols in notepad, I can read letters. In my twig header, i put

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

.
My server is a Linux Centos 6.7.

I don't know if the problem is from serveur, symfony2 (twig), wkhtmltopdf or other...

[PDF display with strange symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WDYG.png)

Comment: Have you tried a different font? A not webfont for example?

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted your template too - or at least the crucial parts

Answer (score 0):

I find, my linux server hasn't good package installed for font... I just do this :

> sudo yum install urw-fonts libXext openssl-devel

and it works nice !